# Vite Build Error with Top-Level Await in Vuex Store Initialization

Tags: laravel, vue.js, build, vuex, vite

I'm currently working on a Vue 3 project with Vuex and Vite. I have a dynamic import for Vuex modules in my store.js file. Here's the relevant code:

```js
import lastStringElement from "../utils/lastStringElement";
import camelToPascal from "../utils/camelToPascal";

import { createStore } from 'vuex';

const modulesArrayToObject = async () => {
    const modules = import.meta.glob('../modules/*/*/*.js');

    let modulesObject = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(modules)) {

        const storeNamespace = lastStringElement(key, '/').replace('.js', '');
        const storeName = `${camelToPascal(storeNamespace)}Store`

        //> keep `await` for dynamic import store modules in VueX
        const { [storeNamespace]: ImportedModule } = await import(
            /* @vite-ignore */
            `../modules/${key.replace('../modules', '')}`
        );

        modulesObject[storeName] = ImportedModule;

    }

    return modulesObject;
}

const createStoreWithModules = async () => {
    const modules = await modulesArrayToObject();
    return createStore({
        modules
    });
};

//* This is a workaround for vite dev process
const store = await createStoreWithModules();

//* This is a workaround for vite build process
//! encapsulate the store in a function to avoid `vite build` error
//! but this will cause a warning in the console in dev process
//? didn't find a better solution for this at the moment 

/*
;   let store;
;   (async () => {
;       store = await createStoreWithModules();
;   })();
*/

export default store;
```

This works fine in development, but when I try to build the project with vite build, I get the following error:

```bash
Transform failed with 1 error:
modules/app.js:129719:14: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 3 overrides)
```

I understand that the error is due to the use of top-level await in my store.js file, which is not supported in the target environment. However, I need to use await to ensure that all modules are imported before creating the Vuex store.

I tried to encapsulate the store initialization in an async IIFE, but this causes a warning in the console during development.

Is there a better way to handle this situation? How can I use dynamic imports with Vuex and Vite without running into this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is supposedly XY problem. It was possible to asynchronously init an app including global stores long before top-level await. In this case you can potentially do `let store` workaround but you need to guarantee that it won't be used until createStoreWithModules promise is fulfilled. Here you just ignore it with AIIFE